# Allowing off-topic questions by necessity

Tags: discussion, off-topic

It is very often the case that users will ask off-topic questions on SO. Mostly I see server-configuration questions, which are flagged, as this is technically not programming and the mods would say this should be asked on, say, Server Fault.

The major problem with this is that Server Fault is comparative tumbleweed neighbourhood, whereas SO is very busy and contains a LOT of users, many of which have the precise expertise sought for by the OP.

I see many off topic questions with a high number of upvotes, answers with high upvotes, and answers that are accepted before the question is closed. Clearly, the users of SO got a lot of mileage out of something that 'technically' shouldn't have been there.

Given the purpose of Stack Exchange is to find answers to problems and queries, is it not acceptable to allow questions to be asked in a community where expertise is so much broader than mere 'programming', as it often goes in hand with very regular server issues, and Server Fault just doesn't have the numbers to get the pleasant speed and efficacy of response seen on Stack Overflow.

This comes to mind because I'm currently waiting for an answer on SF, and I know that if I ninja'd my question on SO, I'd probably get the answer I need before it gets closed.

Comment: So how do you expect ServerFault to ever gain enough users if we don't send the on-topic questions over there?

Comment: Set a bounty on your ServerFault question instead of burdening SO with off-topic questions, is what I'd say.

Comment: You posted that Q on SF less than 15 minutes before complaining about it here... have a bit of patience.

Comment: Yes, I see that argument. But given both are so closely related, perhaps we should consider the whole existance of SF to be redundant. Putting those questions on SO wouldn't, to my mind, make much functional difference. Meanwhile the user's question is pushed to a quiet site where it probably won't be answered. Sucks for that user.

Comment: *"Yes, I know you're a butcher, but you know a lot about cars as well. So what do you think the problem is? The battery?"*....No, just no.

Comment: I'm not complaining @Mat, and it's not my first question on SF (although points for stalking). My point is more to do with the fact I see very many off-topic questions getting a lot of SO attention, whereas on SF they... don't.

Comment: @Bart more like 'You're a butcher, but do you know a lot about running a business?', the two go hand in hand a vast majority of the time.

Comment: @monkeymatrix At which point I would throw a meat cleaver at your head if you persisted asking me off-topic questions. Or to bring it back to SO speak: do it often enough and you'll be banned.

Comment: @Bart, I don't do it myself at all. I respect the rules even if I don't see them being effective. The point is to get answers to questions, not to idealogically follow rules that result in questions going unanswered.

Comment: Very small-minded downvoting going on here. The question is perfectly valid and warrants discussion.

Comment: @monkeymatrix: On meta, downvoting indicates disagreement with the premise, not a dispute with the question having been asked.

Comment: The premise is an invitation for discussion, not stating my support for asking off-topic questions. The discussion is worthy, disagreement or not.

Comment: And as you'll note, this has not yet been closed. Discuss away and ignore the downvotes.

Comment: I feel sorry for users who could get an answer on SO, given it contains users with all of the skill and experience they're looking for, but are forced by rules to post their questions to quiet sites where they are destined to go unanswered. I view it as a failure of the idea behind StackExchange.

Comment: Server Fault's answered percentage is actually a little higher than SO: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic So not only are you more likely to get advice from a proper professional, you're slightly more likely to get an answer period (and that's ignoring the whole off topic thing)

Comment: That's a function of volume. 4.4 million questions vs. 139,000. I'm not surprised the overall rate is higher.

Comment: What would be interesting is a venn diagram of SO vs. SF tags to see just how many of them overlap and discuss **identical** technologies. I'm willing to bet it's significant.

Comment: So you have a problem with a site where your questions is 1) more likely to be answered and 2) if answered, answered by a more qualified audience.....why exactly? Because it might take a bit longer?

Comment: 1) Not more likely - see what I said about volume. If 2 questions are asked and 2 are answered, that's a 100% answer rate. The trouble is a sample of 2 is **not representative**. More questions = lower rate. That should be obvious. and 2) 'More qualified' is entirely subjective and isn't substantiated by any evidence. Fewer users intrinsically means less expertise _exposed to the question_, which is completely contrary to the point.

Comment: @monkeymatrix Have you tried Quora? If not, try it out for a week, and lets see if you still think that SO's laser sharp focus is a bad thing afterwards.

Comment: 140,000 questions and 110,000 users seems like an enormous, sprawling web site by *almost* any standards, not a tumbleweed neighborhood.

Comment: I think you need to look up the definition of 'comparatively'. Sheesh.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see the need for this at all. The sites within the network have a somewhat narrow scope for a reason. It attracts a specific audience with a specific set of knowledge. And it keeps the level of quality within the appropriate subject matter at a high level and well focused.

Allowing off-topic questions would go against that. And what's more, it would simply invalidate the existence of the site where your question would be on-topic. If it's a non-beta site, its existence has been justified already. But if you want to argue against that and propose a site-merge, by all means go ahead.

Yes, there sometimes is an overlap between the respective areas of expertise. And yes, users of one site might be well able to answer a question on an other site's topics. But that does not mean it needs to be included on the other site. If that means you'll have to wait that little bit longer for your answer, so be it.

And even though you disagree, I'd argue that you're more likely to get a good quality answer (and possibly more likely to get an answer at all) on the site where your question is on-topic.

Comment: This is not an answer. You're merely repeating the sentiments of you comments. Looking for some easy rep are we?

Comment: By all means feel free to downvote the answer. And if you must, flag it for moderator attention as "not an answer". You asked for a discussion, you get a discussion.

Comment: That's a laughable suggestion, since I've been downvoted far beyond the point of being able to downvote myself. And it seems you can't flag questions on meta. Either way, still not an answer and you're just gunning for what you think is easy rep. Very distasteful.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the flagging and downvoting. You do need rep for both of those indeed. In the flagging case that's perhaps understandable, but also somewhat strange. In any case, I'm confident that my answer would stand up to scrutiny, so flagging would, I think, be a pointless exercise. And as for rep, they are fake points on a Meta site where rep doesn't really mean a thing... And with almost 200rep on SO, you'll get your free 100 rep bonus here anyway. So don't sweat it.